# custom UISlider subview frame is offset from main view

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, subview

my custom uislider background uiview is offset from original view frame.
and the further the the slider original (x,y) from 0,0 the more the offset.

Please check the image below.

[uislider subview frame offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDlc7.png)

```
import UIKit
```

class customSlier: UISlider {

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.initializeSomeSettings()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }     
    private func initializeSomeSettings() {            
        let view: UIView = UIView()
        view.frame = self.frame
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        self.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: self)
    }    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is at this line:

```
view.frame = self.frame
```

Let's say your scroller is at position (10, 10). Then the background frame is also at position (10,10) in the coordinator of the scroll frame, which is (20,20) in the original view. My suggestion is to replace this line by this:

```
view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.frame.size)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
view.frame = self.bounds
```

Comment: Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users .